# How to perform the same aggregation on every column, without listing the columns?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I have a table with *N* columns. Let's call them `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, ... `cN`. Among multiple rows, I want to get a single row with `COUNT DISTINCT(cX)` for each X in [1, N].

```
c1 | c2 | ... | cn
0  | 4  | ... | 1
```

Is there a way I can do this (in a stored procedure) without writing every column name into the query manually?

## Why?

We've had a problem where bugs in application servers mean we rewrite good column values with garbage inserted later. To solve this, I'm storing the information log-structure, where each row represents a logical `UPDATE` query. Then, when given a signal that the record is complete, I can determine if any values were (erroneously) overwritten.

An example of a single correct record in multiple rows: there is at most one value for each column.

```
| id | initialize_time | start_time | end_time |
| 1  | 12:00am         | NULL       | NULL     |
| 1  | 12:00am         | 1:00pm     | NULL     |
| 1  | 12:00am         | NULL       | 2:00pm   |

Reconciled row:
| 1  | 12:00am         | 1:00pm     | 2:00pm   |
```

An example of an irreconcilable record that I want to detect:

```
| id | initialize_time | start_time | end_time |
| 1  | 12:00am         | NULL       | NULL     |
| 1  | 12:00am         | 1:00pm     | NULL     |
| 1  | 9:00am          | 1:00pm     | 2:00pm   |   -- New initialize time => irreconcilable!
```

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch the column names, or how to do the aggregation?

Comment: I know how to fetch the column names, but I don't know what to do to expand an expression around each column name in the query.

I want to avoid `SELECT COUNT DISTINCT(c1), COUNT DISTINCT(c2), ..., COUNT DISTINCT(cN) FROM ...` in my stored procedure.

Comment: You can do this with dynamic SQL, of course.  By the way, how big is X?

Comment: The total number of columns _N_ is ~30.

Comment: I would have expected that writing that statement for 30 columns would have taken less time than posting this question.

Comment: Personally I'd just add an audit trigger that logged changes to the table, fix the bugs in the application server, and not worry about this over-complex workaround. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need **dynamic SQL** for that, which means you have to create a function or run a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command. Since you cannot return values directly from the latter, a **plpgsql function** it is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE function f_count_all(_tbl text
                                     , OUT columns text[]
                                     , OUT counts bigint[])
  RETURNS record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
       SELECT 'SELECT
         ARRAY[' || string_agg(''''     || quote_ident(attname) || '''', ', ') || '] 
       , ARRAY[' || string_agg('count(' || quote_ident(attname) || ')' , ', ') || ']
       FROM ' || _tbl
       FROM   pg_attribute
       WHERE  attrelid = _tbl::regclass
       AND    attnum  >= 1           -- exclude tableoid & friends (neg. attnum)
       AND    NOT attisdropped       -- exclude deleted columns
       GROUP  BY attrelid
       )
   INTO columns, counts;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_count_all('myschema.mytable');
```

Returns:

```
columns       | counts
--------------+--------
{c1, c2, c3}  | {17, 1, 0}
```

More explanation and links about dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE` in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7915100/939860) - or a couple more here on SO, [try this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20%2bexecute&submit=search).

Related:

- [Count values for every column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841568/count-values-for-every-column-in-a-table)

You could even try and return a polymorphic record type to get single columns dynamically, but that's rather complex and advanced. Probably too much effort for your case. More in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860).