# PostgreSQL: Get values of a register as multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, row, crosstab

Using PostgreSQL 9.3, I'm creating a Jasper reports template to make a pdf report. I want to create reports of different tables, with multiple columns, all with the same template. A solution could be to get values of register as pairs of column name and value per id.

By example, if I had a table like:

```
id | Column1          | Column2     | Column3
-------------------------------------------------
1  | Register1C1      | Register1C2 | Register1C3
```

I would like to get the register as:

```
Id | ColumnName | Value
-----------------------------
1  | Column1    | Register1C1
1  | Column2    | Register1C2
1  | Column3    | Register1C3
```

The data type of value columns can vary!
Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: How many columns do you have ??

Comment: That's the issue. It must work with 'n' columns.

Comment: and what is the Datatype of all columns ???

Comment: Obviously, your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: The datatype is variable too. I'm using Postgres 9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your columns share the same data type and order of rows does not have to be enforced:

```
SELECT t.id, v.*
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('col1', col1)
   , ('col2', col2)
   , ('col3', col3)
      -- etc.
   ) v(col, val);
```

About `LATERAL` (requires Postgres **9.3** or later):

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Combining it with a `VALUES` expression:

- [Crosstab transpose query request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072890/crosstab-transpose-query-request/33073071#33073071)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102743/3684)

For varying data types, the common denominator would be `text`, since every type can be cast to `text`. Plus, order enforced:

```
SELECT t.id, v.col, v.val
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   VALUES
     (1, 'col1', col1::text)
   , (2, 'col2', col2::text)
   , (3, 'col3', col3::text)
     -- etc.
   ) v(rank, col, val)
ORDER  BY t.id, v.rank;
```

In Postgres **9.4** or later use the new unnest() for multiple arrays:

```
SELECT t.id, v.*
FROM   tbl t, unnest('{col1,col2,col3}'::text[]
               , ARRAY[col1,col2,col3]) v(col, val);
           --  , ARRAY[col1::text,col2::text,col3::text]) v(col, val);
```

The commented alternative for varying data types.

#### Full automation for Postgres 9.4:

The query above is convenient to automate for a dynamic set of columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_transpose (_tbl regclass, VARIADIC _cols text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, col text, val text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
     'SELECT t.id, v.* FROM %s t, unnest($1, ARRAY[%s]) v'
   , _tbl, array_to_string(_cols, '::text,') || '::text'))
-- , _tbl, array_to_string(_cols, ',')))  -- simple alternative for only text
   USING _cols;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call - with table name and any number of column names, any data types:

```
SELECT * FROM f_transpose('table_name', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3');
```

Weakness: the list of column names is *not* safe against SQL injection. You could gather column names from `pg_attribute` instead. Example:

- [How to perform the same aggregation on every column, without listing the columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760230/how-to-perform-the-same-aggregation-on-every-column-without-listing-the-columns/13766567#13766567)

Comment: Great! It worked! For my Jasper report I can pass the table name and columns name by parameters and use them as:                             SELECT t.gid, v.col, v.val
FROM   tt.$P!{nombreCapa} t, LATERAL (
   VALUES
    $P!{columnsParameter}
   ) v(rank, col, val)
ORDER  BY t.gid, v.rank;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
    ,unnest(string_to_array('col1,col2,col3', ',')) col_name
    ,unnest(string_to_array(col1 || ',' || col2 || ',' || col3, ',')) val
FROM t
```

---

Try following method:

My sample table name is `t`,to get the `n` columns name you can use this query

```
select string_agg(column_name,',') cols from information_schema.columns where
table_name='t' and column_name<>'id'
```

this query will selects all columns in your table except `id` column.If you want to specify schema name then use `table_schema='your_schema_name'` in *where* clause

To create select query dynamically

```
SELECT 'select id,unnest(string_to_array(''' || cols || ''','','')) col_name,unnest(string_to_array(' || cols1 || ','','')) val from t'
FROM (
        SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',') cols  -- here we'll get all the columns in table t
            ,string_agg(column_name, '||'',''||') cols1 
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 't'
            AND column_name <> 'id'
) tb;
```

And using following `plpgsql` function dynamically creates `SELECT id,unnest(string_to_array('....')) col_name,unnest(string_to_array(.., ',')) val FROM t` and execute.

```
    CREATE OR replace FUNCTION fn ()
RETURNS TABLE (
        id INT
        ,columname TEXT
        ,columnvalues TEXT
        ) AS $$

DECLARE qry TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'select id,unnest(string_to_array(''' || cols || ''','','')) col_name,unnest(string_to_array(' || cols1 || ','','')) val from t'
    INTO qry
    FROM (
        SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',') cols
            ,string_agg(column_name, '||'',''||') cols1
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 't'
            AND column_name <> 'id'
        ) tb;

    RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE format(qry);
END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Call this function like `select * from fn()`

Comment: I think using `unnest(array[col1,col2,col3])` instead of unnesting a an array that was created from a comma separated string) would be more robust (no problem if `col` contains a `,` and it would also preserve the datatypes of the columns.