# Apply the same aggregate to every column in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I am using a proprietary mpp database that has been forked off `psql 8.3`.  I am trying to apply a simple count to a wide table (around 450 columns) and so I was wondering if the best way to do this in terms of a simple sql function.  I am just counting the number of distinct values in a given column as well as the count of the number of null values in the column.  The query i want to generalize for every column is for example

If i want to run the query against the column names i write

```
select
count(distinct names) d_names,
sum(case when names is not null then 1 else 0 end) n_s_ip
from table;
```

> How do i generalize the query above to iterate through every column in the table if the number of columns is 450 without writing out each column name by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since `COUNT()` only counts non-null values, your *query* can be simplified:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT names) AS unique_names
      ,count(names) AS names_not_null
FROM   table;
```

But that's the number of **non-null** values and contradicts your description:

> count of the number of null values in the column

For *that* you would use:

```
count(*) - count(names) AS names_null
```

Since `count(*)` count *all* rows and `count(names)` only rows with non-null `names`.
<sub>Removed inferior alternative after hint by @Andriy.</sub>

To **automate** that for *all* columns build an SQL statement off of the catalog table `pg_attribute` dynamically. You can use `EXECUTE` in a PL/pgSQL function to execute it immediately. Find full code examples with links to the manual and explanation under these closely related questions:

- [How to perform the same aggregation on every column, without listing the columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760230/how-to-perform-the-same-aggregation-on-every-column-without-listing-the-columns)
- [postgresql - count (no null values) of each column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841568/postgresql-count-no-null-values-of-each-column-in-a-table)

Comment: *‘…Or faster with only one scan: …’* – what is that supposed to mean? Would having both `count(*)` and `count(name)` in the same statement require two scans to get the results?

Comment: @AndriyM: Good question. It's done in *one* scan either way. I didn't think this through properly. After running a few tests: the alternative expression is also slightly slower (~ 1%), so I removed the noise.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks for sharing your observation, that's a great thing to keep in mind!

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the repetitive part of query by using `information_scheam.columns`.

```
select 'count(distinct '||column_name||') d_names, sum(case when '||column_name||' is not null then 1 else 0 end) n_s_ip,' 
from information_schema.columns where table_name='table'
order by ordinal_position;
```

The above query will generate `count(...)` and `sum(...)` for each column of `table`. This result can be used as select-list for your query. You can cut&paste the result to the following query:

```
select 
-- paste here
from table;
```

After paste, you have to remove the last comma.

In this way, you can avoid writing `select-list` for 450 columns.